# Xcode/LLVM catch clause not matching derived types

Tags: c++, xcode, exception, llvm

In gcc 4.2, this works:

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    try {
        throw std::runtime_error("abc");
    } catch (const std::exception& ex) {
        std::cout << ex.what();
    }
}
```

In Xcode 4.3.2 (iOS with LLVM 3.1, -std=c++11), this fails with `terminate called throwing an exception`, never reaching the `NSLog(…)` line:

```
#include <stdexcept>

int main() {
    try {
        throw std::runtime_error("abc");
    } catch (const std::exception& ex) {
        NSLog(@"%s", ex.what());
    }

    return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
}
```

But this works:

```
#include <stdexcept>

int main() {
    try {
        throw std::runtime_error("abc");
    } catch (const std::runtime_error& ex) {
        NSLog(@"%s", ex.what());
    }

    return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
}
```

What gives?

Comment: Take out the `const` and tell us what you get.

Comment: @MarkRansom: No change. I tried `…catch (std::exception ex)…` too; again, no change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gcc is correct:

> 15.3p3 A *handler* is a match for an exception object of type `E` if
>
> - ... or
> - the *handler* is of type *cv* `T` or *cv* `T&` and `T` is an unambiguous public base class of `E`, or
> - ...

This sounds like an xcode bug (and a surprisingly basic one!)

Comment: Thanks for the edit @Heatsink. So you actually can put a list in a quote, and now I think I see how.